# problemas para guardar un file en el public_html del hosting en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, phpmyadmin

No sube el archivo(en este caso una imagen) al public del hosting.
Insolitamente algo que me comenzo a suceder hoy. Sin razon. no hice ningun cambio en el controlador. Y en localhost anda perfecto

reinicie el hosting a 0 y volvi a mover todas las carpetas y sigue igual.

Dejo el controlador, donde traigo un request con el file

```
public function store(ArticuloRequest $request)
{
    $articulo = new Articulo($request->all());
    $articulo->usuario_id = \Auth::user()->id;
    $articulo->save();

    $articulo->tags()->sync($request->tags);


    if($request->file('imagen'))
    {
        //Manipulacion de imagenes
        $file= $request->file('imagen');
        $nombre= 'emap_'.time().'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $path = public_path().'/img/articulos';
        $file->move($path,$nombre);

        $img = new Imagen();
        $img->nombre = $nombre;
        $img->articulo()->associate($articulo);
        $img->save();
        dd($path);         
    }


    flash("Se ha creado el articulo ".$articulo->titulo." de forma exitosa!", 'success')->important();

    return redirect()->route('articulos.index');

}
```

el dd($path) me retorna

```
"/home/u923520231/public/img/articulos"
```

La base de dato es u923520231_emap. Estoy usando un hosting compartido (hostinger)

Comment: y tu problema... ¿cual es?

Comment: Estaria en el titulo. pero ahi edite el contenido. Estoy queriendo guardar una imagen en el hosting. pero no lo hace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontre el Problema. Por default la carpeta en laravel es public. Pero no basta con cambiarle el nombre (como tampoco vale cambiar a public el public_html del hosting)

Lo que debemos hacer es cambiarle el nombre a la carpeta del proyecto (a la que el hosting nos ofrece) y luego registrar el cambio dentro del método register de la clase AppServiceProvider ubicada en: app/Providers/AppServiceProvider

```
public function register()
{

    $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
        return base_path().'/public_html';
    });
}
```

Comment: excelente respuesta me funciono perfectamente.